# Laravel Exception after composer dump-autoload

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

Today I `dump-autoloaded` my project and I ran into this error:

```
../Illuminate/Foundation/start.php line 167 undefined index timezone
```

Which says default timezone is not properly set in the app/config.php, while it is set.

Line 167:

```
   165 $config = $app['config']['app'];
   166
   167 date_default_timezone_set($config['timezone']);
```

I've read the solution is `git pull` which totally has confused me and I don't know what to do to solve it.

Comment: see updated question/

Comment: `print_r($config);` bet timezone is missing

Comment: OK I know it is missing, not the timezone but the whole config. Issue is that the config exists, update has done something to it...

Comment: This may not be a solution, but always ensure you're using a recent version of Composer - do a `composer selfupdate` to be sure. I know for a fact Monolog recently changed to PSR-4 which old versions of Composer don't know how to autoload, and so things break . This isn't exactly that case but it's worth updating Composer to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your config is missing a field.

Go to `app/config/app.php` and compare it with the [original](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/config/app.php). Watch out for the line

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

This might fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

what I did and also was suggested in many places in the net was:

Updating the Laravel

Thus, I did the following in the command line and it did the trick:

```
composer update
```